# how to validate category and tag field in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am creating a validation for wordpress post, means user should not be able to submit a post with blank fields.

here is jquery for validating the title and content field, but I am not able to validate the tags and category fields,user should not be able to submit blank categories and blank tags. can anyone please help how to validate category and tags fields in wordpress with jquery.[categories and tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv0rM.png)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // publish button validation
    jQuery('#publish').click(function(){
        $title_value = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#title').val());
        if($title_value == 0 && $title_value != " "){
            alert('please insert title');
            jQuery('.spinner').css("visibility", "hidden");
            jQuery('#title').focus();
            return false;
        }

        $content_value = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#content').val());
        if($content_value == 0 && $content_value != " "){
            alert('Please insert content');
            jQuery('.spinner').css("visibility", "hidden");
            jQuery('#content').focus();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you give us the html of your checkbox ?

Comment: category code [link](https://pastebin.com/xVZWu6sh)

Comment: tags code [link](https://pastebin.com/Ba6Zz4JW)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with JQuery you can get the category container and count the number of input checked.

```js
$("#myButton").on("click", function() {
  /* CATEGORY */
  // Get all the checkbox checked in your category container
  var arrayChecked = $("#categorydiv input:checked");
  alert( arrayChecked.length );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="categorydiv" class="postbox ">
 <div class="handlediv" title="Click to toggle">
 <br />
 </div>
 <h3 class="hndle ui-sortable-handle"><span>Categories</span></h3>
 <div class="inside">
  <div id="taxonomy-category" class="categorydiv">
   <ul id="category-tabs" class="category-tabs">
    <li class="tabs"><a href="#category-all">All Categories</a></li>
    <li class="hide-if-no-js"><a href="#category-pop">Most Used</a></li>
   </ul>

   <div id="category-pop" class="tabs-panel" style="display: none;">
    <ul id="categorychecklist-pop" class="categorychecklist form-no-clear">
     <li id="popular-category-1" class="popular-category">
      <label class="selectit">
       <input id="in-popular-category-1" type="checkbox" value="1">
       Uncategorized
      </label>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>

   <div id="category-all" class="tabs-panel">
    <input type="hidden" name="post_category[]" value="0">
    <ul id="categorychecklist" data-wp-lists="list:category" class="categorychecklist form-no-clear">
     <li id="category-2">
      <label class="selectit"><input value="2" type="checkbox" name="post_category[]" id="in-category-2"> new</label>
     </li>
     <li id="category-6"><label class="selectit">
      <input value="6" type="checkbox" name="post_category[]" id="in-category-6"> news</label>
     </li>
     <li id="category-1" class="popular-category">
      <label class="selectit"><input value="1" type="checkbox" name="post_category[]" id="in-category-1"> Uncategorized</label>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div id="category-adder" class="wp-hidden-children">
    <h4>
     <a id="category-add-toggle" href="#category-add" class="hide-if-no-js">+ Add New Category</a>
    </h4>
    <p id="category-add" class="category-add wp-hidden-child">
     <label class="screen-reader-text" for="newcategory">Add New Category</label>
     <input type="text" name="newcategory" id="newcategory" class="form-required form-input-tip" value="New Category Name" aria-required="true">
     <label class="screen-reader-text" for="newcategory_parent">Parent Category:</label>
     <select name="newcategory_parent" id="newcategory_parent" class="postform">
      <option value="-1">— Parent Category —</option>
      <option class="level-0" value="2">new</option>
      <option class="level-0" value="6">news</option>
      <option class="level-0" value="1">Uncategorized</option>
     </select>
     <input type="button" id="category-add-submit" data-wp-lists="add:categorychecklist:category-add" class="button category-add-submit" value="Add New Category">
     <input type="hidden" id="_ajax_nonce-add-category" name="_ajax_nonce-add-category" value="feff2a33c3">
     <span id="category-ajax-response"></span>
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<button id="myButton">Validate</button>
```

For the tags, I need the HTML code of one tag, to see how can we match with it.

**EDIT : Tags solution**

```js
$("#myButton").on("click", function() {
  var tagsArray = $("#tagsdiv-post_tag .tagchecklist > span");
  alert( tagsArray.length );
});

$(".ntdelbutton").on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest("span").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tagsdiv-post_tag" class="postbox ">
 <div class="handlediv" title="Click to toggle">
  <br>
 </div>
 <h3 class="hndle ui-sortable-handle"><span>Tags</span></h3>
 <div class="inside">
  <div class="tagsdiv" id="post_tag">
   <div class="jaxtag">
    <div class="nojs-tags hide-if-js">
     <p>Add or remove tags</p>
     <textarea name="tax_input[post_tag]" rows="3" cols="20" class="the-tags" id="tax-input-post_tag"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="ajaxtag hide-if-no-js">
     <label class="screen-reader-text" for="new-tag-post_tag">Tags</label>
     <div class="taghint">Add New Tag</div>
     <p>
      <input type="text" id="new-tag-post_tag" name="newtag[post_tag]" class="newtag form-input-tip" size="16" autocomplete="off" value="">
      <input type="button" class="button tagadd" value="Add">
     </p>
    </div>
    <p class="howto">Separate tags with commas</p>
   </div>
   <div class="tagchecklist">
    <span><a id="post_tag-check-num-0" class="ntdelbutton">X</a>&nbsp;tag</span>
    <span><a id="post_tag-check-num-1" class="ntdelbutton">X</a>&nbsp;tag1</span>
    <span><a id="post_tag-check-num-2" class="ntdelbutton">X</a>&nbsp;tag2</span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <p class="hide-if-no-js">
   <a href="#titlediv" class="tagcloud-link" id="link-post_tag">Choose from the most used tags</a>
  </p>
 </div>
</div>
<button id="myButton">Validate</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much kashkain,this is exactly what i was looking for, look if 
 you can help me in tags. here is html [link](https://pastebin.com/jjXgNtb3)

Comment: @MukulSharma I edit my answer and add a solution for the tags

Answer (score 0):

You can do that via specifying tags and categories via [ACF](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj9wf2JmLjUAhXBqo8KHUBtCg8QFgg2MAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwordpress.org%2Fplugins%2Fadvanced-custom-fields%2F&usg=AFQjCNFTanzz4mb4M53jt-vbrKLGvVomlg&sig2=UjyVfyhrEzaSASWWK80rAQ) ,

Create a new custom field from backend,

Select Field Type -> Taxonomy,

Post Type -> post,

Taxonomy -> category,

Allow Null? -> No,

Do same for the post_tag.

Comment: thanks ginani,I have tried that ACF but it is useful only if I want to create a form for user side, it is not working for admin panel default fields.